# Problem occurs in python When the argumets of SubProcess.Run() gets passed with double quotes

Tags: python, subprocess, arguments, double-quotes

When the arguments of SubProcess.Run() gets passed with double quotes,  it is adding extra character `'\'` before and after the double quotes and causing the issue on the actual.exe which gets called by a python script.

```
  def RunWithJsonResponse(self, commandList, argumentList):
        commandList.extend(argumentList)
        process = subprocess.run(commandList, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        '''process already returns in Json format'''
        Response = process.stdout.decode('utf-8')

        '''translate to python dictionary'''
        ResponseDicts = {}
        try:
            ResponseDicts = json.loads(Response)
        except:
            ResponseDicts = json.loads(json.dumps(Response))
            print(Response)
        commandList.clear()
        return ResponseDicts
```

Example command list send by python script = `['C:\\Users\\srw.exe', 'port=COM3', 'writebytes="09 78 00 00"']`

the command received at the.exe end= `C:\\Users\\srw.exe port=COM3 writebytes=\"09 78 00 00"\`

So I would like to find a way of getting rid-off this extra character `'\'`on the other end.

I did the following when the third argument is constructed `'writebytes=' + ' \" ' + 09 78 00 00 + ' \" '` ..but I have no luck

Comment: use / instead of \

Comment: please let me know, where to use / instead of \

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try escaping quotes with `\` in the input to subprocess so in `commandList` in the first place.

Comment: I did the following when the third argument is constructed          'writebytes=' + ' \" ' + 09 78 00 00 + ' \" ' ..but I have no luck